# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object PDO PHP Class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm writing a PHP class called article and it has a bunch of methods like insert, delete and update. I have 3 other functions that follow the same code and they all work so I don't know why I am getting this error. Here is the code I wrote.

```
public function update(){

    //make sure that the article does have an I.D
    if(is_null($this->id)) trigger_error("Article::update(): Attempt to update an Article object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );

    //If there are any PDO errors they will be caught.
    try{
        $connection1 = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $connection1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sqlQuery = "UPDATE articles SET lastEditDate=FROM_UNIXTIME(:lastEditDate), lastEditUser=:lastEditUser, title=:title, content=:content WHERE id = :id";
        $statement->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $statement->bindValue(":lastEditDate", $this->lastEditDate, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindValue(":lastEditUser", $this->lastEditUser, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(":title", $this->title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(":content", $this->content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->execute();
        $connection1 = null;

    }


    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "update():I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }


}
```

I read that you can get it from previous queries so I tried renaming and setting a bunch of the variables to null. I also checked the other threads I could find from this site and other and almost all of them were scope issues, which I don't think is the problem here since all my other functions work. Is there something painfully obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Where do you initialise $statement?

Comment: I hope you don't establish a new database connection in every method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `$connection1->prepare()`, not `$statement->prepare()`.

Comment: Yes I am that retarded should be $statement = $connection->prepare($sqlQuery);